# undefined on return property (XHR)

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

undefined return on xhr post. I don't know where is the problem

```
var d=new XMLHttpRequest();
var data;
d.open("POST",b,!0);
d.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
d.onreadystatechange=function(){
 if(d.readyState==4){
   var data={status:d.status,text:d.responseText};
   return data.text; // this return undefined
  }
};
d.send(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

So first of all why are you returning something from onreadystatechange? Onreadystatechange is a callback function and it's likely that if you use it explicitly (i.e. var foo = d.onreadystatechange ();) you will not have any response yet to process. How exactly are you using that return value?

Second, I'm not sure your syntax is correct for the conditional "4==d.readystate;" I might be wrong but I think you have to use an if statement.

Third you should also make sure d.status==200. If d.readystate == 4 then the request has completed, but not necessarily successfully. You still need to check to make sure the request's HTTP status is 200 OK.

I apologize if I was unclear. This whole thing has been written on a phone. Let me know if you need some examples. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing an async XMLHttpRequest, you cannot return the value from the `onreadystatechange` callback.   Instead, you must use the result in that callback or call some other function and pass it the result.   Returning a value from that callback, just returns it into the bowels of the XHR engine - it never gets into your code.

In addition, you need to make sure that both `readyState === 4` (which means the request has finished) and that you have a successful response code or then you need to handle an error code.  Here's a look at how:

```
var d = new XMLHttpRequest();
d.open("POST", url, true);
d.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/json");
d.onreadystatechange = function(){
    // if request has finished
    if (this.readyState === 4){
        // if request finished successfully
        if (this.status === 200) {
            // process this.responseText here
        } else {
            // process this.status error response code here
        }
     }
  }
};
d.send(data);
```

Also, one character variables does not make your code more readable.  It is highly suggested that you use meaningful names for all variables.  Code can be shortened with a minimizer prior to deployment while retaining the readable version for editing and maintenance.